# how to rotate line segment from another line segment?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: line]

If I have 3 points(P2,P1,P0) and an angle (alpha) between them. What code would find a new point Pt+1 using the angle alpha? The length of the segment is the same between every point.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the x and y value of a point. That's two variables. Therefore you need two equations that relate x and y to have a solvable system.

[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points) shows how to find the angle theta between two vectors. Since the angle between your first vector and your second vector is equal to the angle between your second vector and your third vector, you can set the right sides of the "theta =" equation given in that link equal to each other for each of your vector pairs. At this point you can drop the arc cosine, leaving you with just the fraction on either side of your equation. Then you can go even further and ignore the denominator in that formula, since it is a product of the magnitudes of the vectors and your vector magnitudes are all equal. The first equation that relates your x and y is therefore:

The dot-product of the first and second vectors equals the dot product of the second and third vectors.

The second equation that relates your x and y can be the following:

The magnitude of any of your known vectors equals the magnitude of the vector between P_0 and P_t+1 .

You can use the distance formula to set up that equation.

Now you have a system of two equations with only two unknown values and some fairly straightforward algebra to solve. I solved the first equation for one of the variables in terms of the other, then substituted it in the second equation and used the quadratic formula. It made for some really ugly code when I transcribed all of my algebra, but the cool Spirographs I made were (almost) worth it.

Just a cautionary note: Since this method produces two solution sets (because of the squares), you'll have to decide which of them is the solution you want. It got tedious well before I got to that point, so I decided not to exhaustively figure that part out and I made a crude function to steer my vectors in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your help. I ended up using [this](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) method to find the unknown co-ordinate . The section on intersection of two circles.

Comment: @user1361488 It's not clear to me how you can use that method to solve your problem. Can you write up an answer to your original question that explains how to apply that method to your problem? I really enjoyed this problem and I'd love to see another way to find that point.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually ignore the angle alpha. There is a vector *v* which, when added to P2, produces P0. This same vector *v* added to P1 produces Pt+1. Assuming each point is represented by a tuple (`P0 = (x,y)`), this becomes

```
v = (P0[0] - P2[0], P0[1] - P2[1])
Pt+1 = (P1[0] + v[0], P1[1] + v[1])
```

Comment: (The points (1, 1), (2, 5) and (6, 6) should produce (8.765, 2.941), but your expression gives `v = (-5, -5)` and then `Pt = (-3, 0)`

Comment: @Jason: Hi, how did you get (8.765, 2.941)?

Comment: I got it with a lot of algebra. Start [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points)

Comment: @Jason, i knew how to get the angle between the vectors. I don't know how to use it to obtain the point Pt+1.